# Equivalence of lognormal and exp(normal) probability densities

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I want to see the equivalence of a lognormal distribution with the exponential of a normal distribution. I use the SciPy package in the following and from the corresponding doc the following parametrization:

```
s = sigma
scale = exp(mu)
```

Here's [the link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html). I think that when using this parametrization I do not find deviations from plotting the lognormal pdf and the exp of the normal distribution and additional plotting the normal and the log of the lognormal distribution. I tried to following:

```
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu = 0.5
sigma = 0.2

x1 = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01, loc = mu, scale = sigma),
             norm.ppf(0.99, loc = mu, scale = sigma), 100)
y1 = norm.pdf(x1, loc = mu, scale = sigma)

x2 = np.linspace(lognorm.ppf(0.01, s = sigma, scale = np.exp(mu)),
             lognorm.ppf(0.99, s = sigma, scale = np.exp(mu)), 100)
y2 = lognorm.pdf(x2, s = sigma, scale = np.exp(mu))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].plot(x1,y1, label = "normal")
ax[0].plot(np.log(x2), y2, label = "lognormal")
ax[0].grid()
ax[0].legend()

ax[1].plot(np.exp(x1),y1, label = "normal")
ax[1].plot(x2, y2, label = "lognormal")
ax[1].grid()
ax[1].legend()

fig.show()
```

As you can see, the curves are not the same. Is the SciPy doc wrong and do I have to use a different parametrization, or is my idea of having no differences wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
ax[1].plot(np.exp(x1), y1, label = "normal")
```

should be

```
plot(np.exp(x1), y1*np.exp(-x1), label = "normal")
```

where exp(-x) appears because it is the reciprocal of the derivative of the map x->exp(x). Or, equivalently, it's the derivative of the inverse map (log y)' = 1/y, but expressed in terms of the x variable.

Similarly,

```
plot(np.log(x2), y2, label = "lognormal")
```

should be

```
plot(np.log(x2), y2*x2, label = "lognormal")
```

where we divide by the derivative of logarithm, i.e., divide by 1/x2.

To see why this factor with a derivative appears in the probability density function after a change of variables, see [these notes](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/157), for example. Short explanation is "chain rule from Calculus 1".